# Проверить html цвет на валидность

Tags: php, html

Есть поле INPUT, в который вводится цвет вида `fff` (обязательно без "#" она подставляется в самом html).

Из него данные передаются в PHP и там в HTML прямо подставляется то значение, как его правильнее фильтровать?
И сделать чтобы если оно невалидное, то подставлялось стандартное значение?

Comment: Какие значения цвета валидны? Приведённый в вопросе `ffff` **не является** валидным значением цвета в HTML – должно быть либо 3 либо 6 шестнадцатиричных цифр.

Comment: Спасибо подправил :)

Comment: Варианты типа `rgb(255,128,0)` не рассматриваете?

Comment: Нет, тк в виде #***?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверить валидность можно регуляркой.

Например такой, так как цвет можно задавать как 3-мя, так 6-ми символами:

```
/^([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?$/i
```

Как-то так:

```
$color; // тут у вас строка с цветом
if(preg_match('/^([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?$/i', $color)){
   //  валидный цвет
}
else{
  // не валидный цвет
}
```

Comment: Начало / конец строки надо бы добавить, а то `<script>alert('p0wnd')</script>FF9900` пройдёт, наверное.

Comment: @Sergiks Ну да, поправил ответ.

Comment: Почему `[a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]`, а не `[a-fA-F0-9]` или не `[a-f0-9] ... /i`?

Comment: @Sergiks не знаю, думаете `[a-fA-F0-9]` быстрее?

Comment: У вас код нерабочий – забыли скобку закрыть. Дописали `/i` но не убрали оба варианта `a-z` и `A-Z`. Быстрее, разумеется, оказался более простой вариант регулярки. Проверил, по 3 запуска теста на 1 млн. вызовов для каждого варианта. `[A-Z0-9] .. /i` **быстрее ровно на 20%**

Comment: @Sergiks да, скобочку забыл. Если перфоманс так важен, то да, вероятно стоит использовать более быстрый вариант.

Answer (score 4):

Экономим на спичках! `preg_match()` считается медленной функцией. Быстрее проверить длину строки (только 3 или 6), а затем ASCII код каждого символа в строке:

```
<?php
function isValidColor( $inputColor) {
    $len = strlen( $inputColor);

    // только длиной 3 или 6
    if( $len !== 3  &&  $len !== 6) return false; 
    for( $i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
        $code = ord( substr($inputColor, $i, 1));
        if( $code >= 97  &&  $code <= 102) continue; // a-f
        if( $code >= 65  &&  $code <= 70) continue;  // A-F
        if( $code >= 48  &&  $code <= 57) continue;  // 0-9
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/DK1lHF) с тестами.

Comment: Экономия на спичках? )

Comment: @Suvitruf вот теперь – да!

Comment: Справделивости ради должен заметить, что этот вариант почему-то дико медленный, по сравнению с регулярками: миллион вызовов ф-ии происходит в среднем, за 11с. против 4.5 секунд с короткой регуляркой.

Comment: `strlen` медленный. Он делает кучу лишних операций внутри. Можно переписать на `isset($inputColor{3})`

Comment: @Suvitruf И какой результат будет для строки "AAA3XX"?

Answer (score 4):

Можно проще:

```
function validate_color($str){
    return (($l=strlen($str))==3)||($l==6)) 
    && sscanf($str,"%x", $color);
}

print(validate_color("AAA")? "цвет валидный": "цвет не валидный");
```

P.S. Снимаем вопросы по быстродействию:

```
function validate_color_sscan($str){
    return ($l=strlen($str)) && (($l==3)||($l==6)) && sscanf($str,"%x", $color);
}

function test_sscan($str){
    for($i=0; $i<2000000; $i++) $v=($l=strlen($str)) && (($l==3)||($l==6)) && sscanf($str,"%x", $color);
}

function validate_color_preg($str){
    return preg_match('/^[A-F0-9]{3}([A-F0-9]{3})?$/i', $str);
}

function test_preg($str){
    for($i=0; $i<2000000; $i++) $v=preg_match('/[a-f0-9]{3}([a-f0-9]{3})?$/i', $str);
}

print(validate_color_sscan("AAA")? "<br>цвет валидный": "<br>цвет не валидный");
print(validate_color_preg("AAA")? "<br>цвет валидный": "<br>цвет не валидный");

$time0 = microtime(true);
test_sscan($str);
$time1 = microtime(true);
test_preg($str);
$time2 = microtime(true);

printf("<br>test_sscan x 2000000: %d mcs", $time1-$time0);
printf("<br>test_preg x 2000000: %d mcs", $time2-$time1);
```

Результаты:

```
цвет валидный
цвет валидный
test_sscan x 2000000: 8 mcs
test_preg x 2000000: 14 mcs
```

Comment: 5.9 секунд на 1 млн. вызовов у меня получилось. Пока рекордсмен – вариант с регуляркой, только не тот, что в ответе @Suvitruf, а `[a-z0-9]` с ключём `/i`

Comment: @Sergiks Такая регулярка ничего не проверит. Ни буквы, ни регистр не учтены.

Comment: `/^[A-F0-9]{3}([A-F0-9]{3})?$/i` – я написал и тестировал такое регулярное выражение. И оно быстрее всех других вариантов здесь работает, при этом проходит все тесты.

Comment: @Sergiks Совсем другое дело, простенько и со вкусом. Я своё тоже чуток обновил

Comment: @Sergiks У меня быстрее

Answer (score 3):

```
  preg_match('/^([a-f0-9]{6}|[a-f0-9]{3})$/i', $color)
```

Answer (score 2):

Хотелось найти еще какой-либо альтернативный вариант, помимо регулярных выражений. Откопал функцию [ctype_xdigit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-xdigit.php) - проверяет, является ли строка шестнадцатеричным значением (без символа решетки). Не ручаюсь на счет производительности, не пользовался ей.

```
ctype_xdigit('fff'); // true
```

Comment: `ctype_xdigit('FFFF'); // true` – это валидное 16-ричное число, но не валидный HTML цвет. По условиям задачи надо получить `false` если не ровно 3 или 6 символов.